# Can't Join Table, ID_Dosen , ID_Dosen(Primary Key)

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have tried to combine three tables between `mst_Dosen`, `mst_MK`, `tst_Dosen_MK`. I just want to display `ID, ID_Dosen, Name, ID_MK, Nama_MK`.

These are my tables:
[image]

I want to join table: tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen get form mst_Dosen.ID_Dosen and tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK get form mst_MK.ID_MK.

like that :
[image]

I have tried it, but still I cannot do it.

```
"SELECT tst_Dosen_MK.ID, tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen, mst_Dosen.Nama, tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK, mst_MK.Nama_MK
FROM (tst_Dosen_MK INNER JOIN mst_Dosen ON (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen = mst_Dosen.ID_Dosen) AND (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen = mst_Dosen.Nama)) INNER JOIN mst_MK ON (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK = mst_MK.ID_MK) AND (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK = mst_MK.Nama_MK);
"
```

The message "type mismatch in expression"

Comment: Why are you joining on `Nama` and `Nama_MK`? Are they ID's, are they the same type as your ID's? If not, leave them out of the join.

Answer (score 0):

1) Leave irrelevant stuff out of your JOIN-conditions.
2) Use aliases to make your query readable.

Doing that leads to this:

```
SELECT dm.ID
     , dm.ID_Dosen
     , d.Nama
     , dm.ID_MK
     , m.Nama_MK
FROM       tst_Dosen_MK dm
INNER JOIN mst_Dosen    d ON dm.ID_Dosen = d.ID_Dosen
INNER JOIN mst_MK       m ON dm.ID_MK = m.ID_MK;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error, 'Type mismatch in expression', indicates that what is one of the fields that you are passing with a query is not valid.

Here: `tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen = mst_Dosen.Nama` you compare different data types.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.ID_Dosen, B.Nama, A.ID_MK, C.Nama_MK 
FROM   tst_Dosen_MK as A, mst_Dosen as B, mst_MK as C
WHERE  A.ID_Dosen = B.ID_Dosen AND A.ID_MK = C.ID_MK
```

Or this:

```
SELECT tst_Dosen_MK.ID, tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen, mst_Dosen.Nama, tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK, mst_MK.Nama_MK 

FROM (tst_Dosen_MK INNER JOIN mst_Dosen ON (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_Dosen = mst_Dosen.ID_Dosen)) INNER JOIN mst_MK ON (tst_Dosen_MK.ID_MK = mst_MK.ID_MK))
```

Comment: not working "Type mismatch in expression."

but thanks wellington :)